# Is there a way to increase the size of the post editor in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

The editing textarea in WordPress is too small for anything but short posts. How do I make it bigger?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the settings for writing, the first option is "Size of the post box", juste increase this number.

You can also just drag the bottom right corner down to increase it directly when writing a post.

Comment: Not entirely positive, but I think the second sentence is browser dependent (and I rely on it!)